# Independent thread in Asp.net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.5, long-running-processes

```
protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FineTuneDB();// Long Task running in db
    SendSMStoAllClients();// Using Twolio API to send sms to all client long task

    lblText.Text = "Button click is completed our system threads working on your request";
}
```

Is this possible that on button click I can response to client and independent long task going on separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about whether task is completed or not, you call `FineTuneDB` method like this.

```
Action fineTuneDB = FineTuneDB;
fineTuneDB.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

[Asynchronous Method Invocation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14931/Asynchronous-Method-Invocation)

**Updated:**

```
Action<int, string> fineTuneDB = FineTuneDB;
fineTuneDB.BeginInvoke((int)Session["id"], 
   Session["name"].ToString(), null, null);

// Your method will be like this
public void FineTuneDB(int id, string)
{

}
```

Comment: sorry here I got one issue using this technique it works fine but I found that sessions values are not available because httpcontext.current is null durign finetuneDB method

Comment: Yes, it is true. If you want to pass the variables, use the second method.